Reflections on affine quadric hypersurfaces
Let $f\colon\mathbb{Z}^n\otimes\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}$ be a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form and consider the affine quadric hypersurface $$
X:=\{f(x,x)+2=0\}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^n.
$$
For each $x\in X$, there is a reflection $r_x\colon X\to X$ given by $r_x (y)=y+f(x,y)x$. Let $R$ be the subgroup of automorphisms of $X$ generated by all these reflections.
The question I want to ask is: does $R$ act transitively on $X$?

Not necessarily, not even if $f$ is negative definite:
then $X$ is a Euclidean root system with all norms equal,
and $R$ is its Weyl group, which is transitive iff
the root system is irreducible.
The first counterexample appears for $n=2$ with $f$ being
the standard negative-definite form $f(x,x') = -(x_1 x_1' + x_2 x_2')$.
Here $X = \{(\pm1,\pm1)\}$.  Taking $x = (1,1)$,
we find for all $y = (y_1,y_2)$ that
$$
r_x(y) = (y_1,y_2) - (y_1+y_2) (1,1) = (-y_2,-y_1),
$$
which is always either $y$ or $-y$ for any $y \in X$,
so there are two orbits $\{ \pm (1,1) \}$ and $\{ \pm (1,-1) \}$.
There are also more complicated examples with $f$ indefinite.
